# Database design - dogmatic view?

Tags: database-design

I'm an application developer (full stack, I'm not shy of SQL, actually prefer it to some ORM solutions).

The database architect (that has no coding role) for the project I'm working on is adamant that I should re-use an existing structure that was not designed in mind with the set of requirements that I have. I've looked at the impacts of the said design and I could see impact on existing code base because of assumptions that were made in the code based on the initial design. I would like to use a separate structure (similar but not identical) that would support my code.

What reasons do you think my database architect has? (Because I've only got the **"there is a table there - use it"** statement which doesn't make for me).

I've tried to approach the support of my design based on:

- It's not inferior to his option from a technical point of view.
- It's safer from a code base perspective.
- It's less coupled for future enhancements.
- It's faster when the requirement conditions are met (millions of rows).

If it's any help:

- The existing structure is called Queue. You can see where this could be an issue: a lot of things can be modeled as queues.
- When it should matter my structure would hold millions of rows which will skew any indexes and potentially slow down the actual queues recorded there.
- Multiple types of queues exist in the system now with different setups (but when tried to setup mine I've hit issues in the existing code base hence my concern).

You could say that is a case of "normalization" but the data itself is not repeated, there is no report that will run across the entire set and if used it will require to use some discriminators to differentiate my stuff from the normal queues.

I guess, at the end of the day, the questions I don't have an answer for are:

- What are the compelling reasons to re-use a set of tables when the information you want to retain in them is not overlapping? (The database architect was not able to respond to this).
- What's the (importance/cost/risk) of having a similar cloned structure?

Comment: Your question is quite vauge - I mean how are we supposed to advise you? You tell us you have a better structure than that of your DB designer/team lead. Sure - maybe you do - but how can we tell? We don't have your table structures - before and after. This is a kind of open-ended question which are (unfortunately) considered off-topic here. I'm **not** going to VTC (Vote To Close) - but I think that it will ultimately be closed. You may wish to try with more specific questions? Take the tour, check out the Help Centre to see what's off- and on-topic here. p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: Thanks @Vérace. I've edited my question.

Comment: It's probably better to give us some examples, I suggest X the architect says Y (post the ERD for example). Right now you're asking SE opinion about a model they haven't seen. The best answers to this question atm would be based on how to work together with your architect.

Comment: A table isn't just an array of typed values. It has a *meaning*. If the new data matches the semantics of the existing table it logically belongs there. Otherwise it gets its own table. There could still be good reasons for holding logically equivalent values in physically different ways.